# CSS border image only working on top and bottom

Tags: html, css, border-image

I am trying to add an image for my border, but right now it only appears to be working for the top and bottom. I need it to go around the entire container.

Here is the border image:

[image]

Here is what my container currently looks like:

[image]

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="panel-blurb">
            <p class="panel-blurb-text">    
                Ad molestiae hendrerit mei,
                nobis persius deleniti et eum, ea ullum electram dignissim 
                his. Dicit dolorem moderatius in pro, dicat choro propriae ad mei.
                Dicat legimus efficiendi sit in. Natum falli cu nec. Id hinc regione 
                alienum vel, cu vide atomorum mel. Munere commodo at eos, te laudem docendi 
                volumus pro, maiorum dignissim ex sea.
            </p>
            <div class="panel-link-wrapper">
                <a class="panel-link" href="#">VIEW DETAILS</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.panel-blurb{
    width: 88.5%;
    background-color: #54504f;
    padding: 25px;
    border-width: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: url(images/border-min.png) 30;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting your `border-image` slice value to a percent, like `30%` instead of just `30`? Without knowing what your original border-image is, it's somewhat difficult to determine what could be causing the issue.

Comment: @TylerRoper I added the image. Adding a percentage value does add a border to all sides, but it's completely distorted.

Comment: @TylerRoper that can be unitless (but I agree that it'd be very helpful to know what the original image looks like)

Comment: @JordanCarter thanks guys. Here's a JSFiddle for anyone else who wants to play around with it like I am: https://jsfiddle.net/4hd6cqb5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without border-image

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #545050;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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'), url('data:image/png;base64,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'),
url('data:image/png;base64,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'
),
url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABEAAAARCAIAAAC0D9CtAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuMTCtCgrAAAABeklEQVQ4T12TDbLDIAiEPWLjP6hJev9LvA9N89LO0BlFll021EmOR5f33oij1RJ8fL1+ogY/pKya91CXvW8lnQvWZdRcwvYEpG27C86hvSYXt1eJvtfMnR5nE7JkFiD7TRHSqj0NHVpr9BMTvJa4z4cJq70k2MoE7FqoJkBCSLHjJylyoT3VC3aowRqAVhc/gCGZjJbkNEXmI7gPg8nF1uVqwRhddil0YVq6GIYeltWiKeySLz/u6GodAWBdt14OW2xKuponWYBpfWLoNcWbSQRyFibdGBsaSQ8Ms5HkiTM1nPEg9FpgRCE2oPhH25Jt7pHHbimupjC0LFuIpweL/Dq3egCbk7sa4bH2XcyTVWQtpk4O/y0mG8HubBIDtnCxZ8Rc39Tz1PJ0H5GjQYsimwcPoDJVa6P63J3PprIKtlZTMBKgxVjjaXzKKYBYDGm7F9Q2y2B9SqAAD/DeRE+L+DKsffps9B1TyPVfALb24FLMSEbyDYDqCzP0D2XlLfeYeYFOAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'
);
  background-position: top center, bottom center, center left, center right;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: And I think you meant `background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y;`?

Comment: @henry sry see that again

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Thank you, this works. Could you please explain it, and how you did it? Also, I hate to be picky, but there is a very tiny gap between the border top image and the border left and right ones. Is there a way to make them perfectly flush against each other?

Comment: @JordanCarter Yeah. In css3 u can multiplay backgorund-image. I use 4 background - top, right, bottom and left.  background. Each pattern includes small square of your image of border, ~16x16px. Each background repeating only along the respective borders. Backgrounds for vertical borders in the graphical editor rotate 90 degrees. What you see base64 is just a way to integrate images into CSS code.
That one pixel can be corrected if precisely cut your image. I'm just in a hurry.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov I see, but how did you get it to work on all four borders when you only specified three URLS? Also, did the program output the image as data? Is there any advantage of doing it this way?

Comment: @JordanCarter not three, a four... scroll. 
base64 in this case no advantage. I just would have had to load small images in the Image Hosting. but base64 approach speeds up the loading of pages.

Comment: Interesting...so if I could base encode my images, would you recommend it as best practice? I could losslessly compress it first, and then base encode it later. Anyway, thank you so much for your help. I am selecting this as the best answer.

Comment: Encode in base64 only small pics. Else ur CSS code will be BIG size. Faster loading due to the fact that html protocol on one domain allocates only 5 download streams... Tnx. )

Answer (score 0):

You forget add round

You can do it like this

```
.panel-blurb{
    width: 88.5%;
    background-color: #54504f;
    padding: 25px;
    border-width: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: url(images/border-min.png) 30 round;
}
```

Comment: Tried that. Same issue : (

Answer (score 0):

Try this .It will give border around all sides

```
border-image:url('images/border-min.png') 30 30 round;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some work of my own and i think what you have done is only save the image for one side of a border if you duplicate it and make a box like a border it should work. I had the same issue you have to take into consideration each side of the border. When i did this it solved the issue just make a new image add the top and bottom flip that image crop it so it fits and you are golden i set mine to `11 11 11 11 round`.

I'm not sure if it will work for you but it worked for me.